# "single in a run off"

Tags: meaning, phrases

> Kang Jung-jo of the Pittsburgh Pirates **singles in a run off** Miami
>   Marlins pitcher Jose Urena during the first inning of their game
>   Tuesday in Pittsburgh. Kang, who started at third base and hit fifth
>   in the batting order, went 2-for-3 in the Pirates’ 5-1 victory. The
>   former Nexen Heroes player is hitting .316. in his first year in Major
>   League Baseball. [AP/NEWSIS]

I'm having trouble understanding the phrase *singles in a run off*.

The word *single* has two meanings relevant to baseball:

1. to cause the advance of (a base runner) by a one-base hit.
2. to cause (a run) to be scored by a one-base hit (often followed by in or home).

I guess #1 is correct in the referenced article.

I'm not sure how *single* and *in a run* are related.

Additionally, does *off* mean *against*?

Comment: It might be clearer if you divide it thusly: "singles in a run // off Marlins pitcher Urena".  Thus you are looking at 2 phrases, not one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually #2 is correct. What the sentence is saying is that Kang Jung-Jo hit a *single* which allowed a previous batter's *run* to complete (ie a previous batter made it all the way around the bases), thus scoring a point. Kang 'singled in' a previous player's run.

'Off' is used in reference to the pitcher. You might hit a home run *off* your brother's pitch, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the word **single** have two meanings in baseball, but neither of your meanings is perfectly correct.

**Single** can be a noun, in which it simply means a **one-base hit**.  As a verb, it means **to get a one-base hit**.  It has nothing to do with what happens to the men on base, except that if you reach first base and someone else is out on the play, it's not considered a hit at all.

**Double, triple** and **homer** have parallel meanings for multi-base hits.

A **run**, of course, is a point scored in baseball, every time a player successfully circles the bases and reaches home plate.

So to **single in a run** is to get a one-base hit that allows a base runner to score (usually from second or third base).  **Off the pitcher**, as correctly answered above, indicates that Jose Urena was the pitcher who allowed Kang the hit that resulted in a run batted in (RBI) on that play. So you are right in thinking that here, **off** basically means **against**.

Answer (score 1):

As Steven Littman suggests in his answer, the verb *singles* means "to hit a ball and safely reach first base, while moving any runners already on base over to at least the next available base safely." When a one-base hit enables a runner already on base to score (by reaching home plate safely), the idiomatic way of expressing the achievement is to say that the batter (or the batter's *hit* or [in this case] the batter's *single*) drove in the runner (or *drove in a run*).

But why "drove **in**" or "singled **in**"? In baseball parlance, a runner who successfully scores a run "comes **in** to score"; and if he scores because someone else got a hit (a single a double, a triple, or a home run) or even a productive out, that hitter is said to have "driven him **in**."

In baseball scoring, runs are "charged" to the pitcher who originally let the runner get on base. But when a batter hits safely, as Steven Littman observes, his hit is described as coming "off" the pitcher who threw that pitch. In this wording, *off* simply means *against*.

Put it all together, and you have

> Kang Jung-jo of the Pittsburgh Pirates singles in [that is, *drives in with a single*] a run off [that is, *against*] Miami Marlins pitcher Jose Urena during the first inning of their game...